# How to connect an MFC control to a custom control in the visual dialog editor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I have created a custom control in the MFC visual dialog designer, as shown below:

[image: Visual Dialog Editor screenshot]

However, I am unsure how I can link my custom control (in this case I have created a class `CGraphCtrl` which inherits from `CWnd`) to the region that I have created in the visual editor, I assumed that I would be able to do this when I called `CGraphCtrl::Create`, however, as that takes a `const CRect&` as an argument, this overrides the region specified. I am calling `CGraphCtrl::Create` in `CStockManagerDlg::OnInit` as follows:

```
m_graphCtrl.Create( _T("STATIC"), _T("Graph Control"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 
                    CRect( 0, 0, 100, 100 ), this, IDC_GRAPH );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CStatic control in the visual dialog editor. Then right-click on it and create a control member variable like CStatic m_graphCtrl. Then edit that code to make it a CGraphCtrl m_graphCtrl. This attaches your code to the original CStatic.